# Add 3rd party java script for ember js

Tags: ember.js

Im beginner for the `emebr-js`  im create the application for my university project, im add some 3rd party calendar for my application, i want to add some java script in this application where's  to include  this 3rd part script, im try to add this  `route` **>** `Profile.js` but not working, how can i add this script for the `profile.hbs`

`hbs` page name `Profile.hbs`

this is my script

```
    <script type="text/javascript">



  var calendarPicker2 = $("#dsel2").calendarPicker({
    monthNames:["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
    dayNames: ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"],
    useWheel:true,
    //callbackDelay:500,
    years:0,
    months:0,
    days:3,
    showDayArrows:false,
    callback:function(cal) {

    }});

    </script>
```

Comment: Where `calendarPicker`  is defined ?. Create component `my-profile` and include it in profile.hbs template like `{{my-profile }}`and include datePicker initialization code in `didInsertElelement` life cycle hook method.

Comment: sir, can i add for  this script ` profile.hbs`

Comment: Dont do that. thats not supported. You just run the below command, `ember g component my-profile` it will create .hbs and .js file for you

Comment: sir, this is my html part   `<div id="bookingdetails-calender">
    <a href="calendarPicker.html#" onclick="calendarPicker2.changeDate(new Date())"></a>
    <div id="dsel2" style="width:390px;margin-left:-100px;"></div>
   </div>`

Comment: that's ok. which third party are you using for calendarPicker

Comment: sir this html code  format is nor ember format its is correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149076/discussion-between-kumkanillam-and-core114).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will encourage you to look for ember-addons from https://emberobserver.com/

So if just want to use [w3widgets.com/responsive-calendar](http://w3widgets.com/responsive-calendar/#install%20,)

For this code,

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/responsive-calendar.js"></script>
<link href="css/responsive-calendar.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

**How to setup ember to use plugin,**

- jquery.js is already bundled in Ember so no need for special handling.
- Place `responsive-calendar.js` file in `app-name/vendor/responsive-calendar.js` and in `app-name/ember-cli-build.js` file iclude `app.import('vendor/responsive-calendar.js')`
- Place `responsive-calendar.css` file in `app-name/styles/responsive-calendar.css` and open `app.css` and include the below line `@import 'responsive-calendar.css';`

Thats it now plugin is ready for use.

**How to use it,**

Create component called my-calendar by running the command `ember g component my-calendar`, it will create my-calendar.hbs and my-calendar.js file.

In my-calendar.hbs, place the required markup code,

```
<!-- Responsive calendar - START -->
<div class="responsive-calendar">
  <div class="controls">
      <a class="pull-left" data-go="prev"><div class="btn"><i class="icon-chevron-left"></i></div></a>
      <h4><span data-head-year></span> <span data-head-month></span></h4>
      <a class="pull-right" data-go="next"><div class="btn"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></div></a>
  </div><hr/>
  <div class="day-headers">
    <div class="day header">Mon</div>
    <div class="day header">Tue</div>
    <div class="day header">Wed</div>
    <div class="day header">Thu</div>
    <div class="day header">Fri</div>
    <div class="day header">Sat</div>
    <div class="day header">Sun</div>
  </div>
  <div class="days" data-group="days">
    <!-- the place where days will be generated -->
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Responsive calendar - END -->
```

and in my-calendar.js file,

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    didInsertElement() {
        this.$('.responsive-calendar').responsiveCalendar();
    }
});
```

That's it. You can include my-calendar component in any template like `{{my-calendar }}`

Comment: Sir, Thank you for the valuable explain and your time  for me